# Add heading before existing table with python docx library

Tags: python, ms-word, docx

I have a word document with existing table. I am able to add rows to the table, now I am trying to add heading before existing table, but I do not know how. This is my code:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('template.docx')

document.add_heading('Heading1', level=1)

table = document.tables[1]
table.row_cells(0)[0].text = 'description'
table.row_cells(0)[1].text = 'vulnerability'
table.row_cells(0)[2].text = ''

document.save('result.docx')
```

This is the result I get. I heading1 is added after table. I would like to add it before.

[image]

The result I would like to get.

[image]

In Template.docx is just a teable, which looks like this:
[template.docx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6af6A.png)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share `'template.docx'`?

Comment: @Alderven I have add it to my question. It is just file with the table.

Comment: Get the range of the table using tables(1).range then insert a paragraph before the range then set the style to 'Heading 1'.  If docx can't manage this then use win32com.

Comment: @Freeflow can you write some code how to do that? I tried something like you recommended without success.